Oracle SQL Problem - needed to return spesific rows from a table
I'm working with a campaign management system called Unica that performs SQL queries behind the scenes.
In my job, I have a contacthistory table, which holds the contacts for each customer who turns out to be suitable for the population in the campaign.
We have 4 contactstatusid (1-find suitable, 2-send to a channel, 5-contacted, 6-lead closed)
The logic goes like this status number 1 comes first and a few minutes later after the communication channel gets this customer the status will change to 2. and 5 comes while some status in the CRM was changed.
We can get more than one row with the same customerid but any customer can be suitable for the campaign once a day but more than one time in a lifetime.
I want to get customer IDs for customers that have any row with status ID number 2 and don't have a fitted row with status ID 5. (they are fitted if the contactdatetime for both statuses are in the same day) and i need the rows for channel = 'CRM'
I tried to tell if this customer has status id 5 so don't give him back but then I missed a lot of rows of this customer that don't have fitted status ID 5.
I've also tried to make some joins and things but I didn't get the right outcomes.
select *
from unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv
where channel = 'CRM'
and contactstatusid = '2'
and contactdatetime not in
    (select a.custid, a.contactdatetime
    from unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv a
    inner join unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv b
    on a.custid = b.custid
    where a.channel = b.channel
    and extract(day from a.contactdatetime)=extract(day from b.contactdatetime)
    and extract(month from a.contactdatetime)=extract(month from b.contactdatetime)
    and extract(year from a.contactdatetime)=extract(year from b.contactdatetime)
    and a.channel = 'CRM'
    and a.contactstatusid = '2'
    and b.contactstatusid = '5'
);


Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; and the expected output for that sample data.

I think you have to add the customer ID in the selection
 select * from unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv c

    where channel = 'CRM'

    and a.contactstatusid = '2'

    and to_char(contactdatetime,'DDMMYYYY') not in

        (select to_char(a.contactdatetime,'DDMMYYYY')

        from unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv a

        inner join unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv b

        on a.custid = b.custid

        where a.channel = b.channel

        and extract(day from a.contactdatetime)=extract(day from b.contactdatetime)

        and extract(month from a.contactdatetime)=extract(month from b.contactdatetime)

        and extract(year from a.contactdatetime)=extract(year from b.contactdatetime)

        and a.channel = 'CRM'

        and a.contactstatusid = '2'

        and b.contactstatusid = '5'
        and a.custid=c.custid
    );


Hey, I've tried this one and it doesn't work. now I have a problem with the contactdatetime that it's bringing back.

You can use conditional aggregation within an analytic function to count the number of rows with contactstatusid of 5 for each custid, channel and day and then filter to only show the rows where the count is zero:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ch.*,
         COUNT(CASE contactstatusid WHEN '5' THEN 1 END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY custid, channel, TRUNC(contactdatetime)
         ) AS contactstatusid_5_count
  FROM   unica_campaign.ua_contacthistory_dlv ch
  WHERE  channel = 'CRM'
  AND    contactstatusid IN ('2', '5')
)
WHERE  contactstatusid_5_count = 0;

